# Bootstrap Vue accordion not expanding with id from array

Tags: vue.js, accordion, bootstrap-vue

I have an array for a **Bootstrap-Vue** `accordion` that includes an `id`. The button appears with my text but will not expand on clicking. I'm fairly new to coding in general and this is my first week using **Vue** so super-new to it.

I've tried creating an `id` of "`accordion-1`", "`accordion-2`" etc. and feeding the `v-b-toggle` and collapse id "`accordionItems.accId`". I've also tried having the accId be a number (1, 2, etc.) and feeding the v-b-toggle and collapse ids as "`'accordion1' + accId`" and also `+item.id` and +"`accordionItems.accId`. Lastly I tried adding the reactive: true statement because I'm getting the message about reactivity in the Console but nothing works.

```
  <b-card no-body class="mb-1" v-for="item in accordionItems" :key="item.accId">
    <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
      <b-button block v-b-toggle="'accordion-' + accordionItems.accId" variant="primary"> {{ item.button }}
      </b-button>
    </b-card-header>
    <b-collapse id="'accordion-' + accordionItems.accId" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
      <b-card-body>
        <b-card-text>{{ item.text }}</b-card-text>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Accordion",
  data() {
    return { reactive: true,
      accordionItems: [
        {
          accId: 1,
          button: `Who played Burt and Heather Gummer in Tremors?`,
          text: `Answer: Burt: Michael Gross, Heather: Reba McEntire`
        },

        {
          accId: 2,
          button: `In "The Bachelor and the Bobby-Soxer" (1947), what line does Dick Nugent (Cary Grant) use to convince Susan Turner (Shirley Temple) he's no more mature than boys her own age?`,
          text: `Answer: "Mellow greetings, yookie dookie!"`
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I inspect with **Vue**, I can see the id is showing as "`'accordion-' + accordionItems.accId`" so I know I'm missing something. I'm expecting to click on the question and have it expand to show the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "bind" to ID:

```html
    <b-collapse :id="'accordion-' + accordionItems.accId" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
      <b-card-body>
        <b-card-text>{{ item.text }}</b-card-text>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-collapse>
```

Note the `:` before `id=`.  This instructs Vue that the value in the quotes is a javascript expression.

What was happening with `id="'accordion-' + accordionItems.accId"` is that Vue sees the value between the double quotes as a string literal, not a JavaScript Expression.

Comment: Holy moly thank you! Adding the colon worked and I appreciated the explanation. My apologies for not responding sooner but npm run serve was hanging and I had to comment out everything and add it back one item at a time to find out why. I had no idea how to troubleshoot the issue so it took me more than a day to do it.